# Slack Workflow API Call to get Data

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I want to create a Slack Workflow that is triggered via an Emoji. As part of the Workflow, I need to make an API call to get some data as one of the steps. Specifically, I am looking for a Workflow where you can react with a `help` emoji on a question, the workflow would find out who is oncall, and then ping that person to help with the request.

Is this possible?